# How to configure docker/docker-compose to use Nexus by default instead of docker.io?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-desktop, testcontainers

I'm trying to use TestContainers to run JUnit tests.
However, I'm getting a `InternalServerErrorException: Status 500: {"message":"Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: Forbidden"}` error.

Please note, that I am on a secure network.

I can replicate this by doing `docker pull testcontainers/ryuk` on the command line.

```
$ docker pull testcontainers/ryuk
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: Forbidden
```

However, I need it to pull from our nexus service: `https://nexus.company.com/18443`.
Inside the docker-compose file, I'm already using the correct nexus image path. (Verified by manually starting it with docker-compose. However TestContainers also pulls in additional images which are outside the docker-compose file. It is these images that are causing the failure.

I'd be glad for either a Docker Desktop or TestContainers configuration change that would fix this for me.

Note: I've already tried adding the host URL for nexus to the Docker Engine JSON configuration on the dashboard, with no change to the resulting error when doing `docker pull`.

Comment: Does this help you? https://forums.docker.com/t/error-response-from-daemon-get-https-registry-1-docker-io-v2/23741/10

Comment: No, that's about logging in. I'm not logging into an account on docker.io. I'm trying to use a completely different repo.

Comment: You mentioned that you are on a secure network. My guess is that the firewall is preventing you from accessing resources on docker.io, where the "additional images" you mentioned are pulled from.

Comment: That is correct @JR.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the version `1.15.1` Testcontainers allow to automatically append prefixes to all docker images. In case your private registry is configured as a docker hub mirror this functionality should help with the mentioned issue.

Quote from the [documentation](https://www.testcontainers.org/features/image_name_substitution/#automatically-modifying-docker-hub-image-names):

> You can then configure Testcontainers to apply the prefix registry.mycompany.com/mirror/ to every image that it tries to pull from Docker Hub. This can be done in one of two ways:
>
> - Setting environment variables TESTCONTAINERS_HUB_IMAGE_NAME_PREFIX=registry.mycompany.com/mirror/
> - Via config file, setting hub.image.name.prefix in either:
>
>   - the ~/.testcontainers.properties file in your user home directory, or
>   - a file named testcontainers.properties on the classpath

Basically set the same prefix you did for the images in your docker-compose file.

If you're stuck with older versions for some reason, a deprecated solution would be to override just the `ryuk.container.image` property. Read about it [here](https://www.testcontainers.org/features/configuration/#customizing-images).

Comment: Thanks, this got me past that issue and onto newer and better issues :P

Answer (score 0):

The process is described on [this page](https://docs.docker.com/registry/recipes/mirror/):

Add the following to your Docker daemon config:

```json
{
  "registry-mirrors": ["https://nexus.company.com:18443"]
}
```

Make sure to restart the daemon to apply the changes.

Comment: I tried that and restarted Docker Desktop already. It didn't make any difference.