# Can a java TestContainer be started without attempting to call the default registry?

Tags: testcontainers

At work, we have decided we would like to use the java [TestContainers](https://www.testcontainers.org/) package, and it has fallen to me to learn and implement this package. It is important to note that security is a top priority at work, so we are behind a proxy and run our own registry to contain our docker images.

This is what I've got so far.

```
var dockerImage = DockerImageName.parse("<secure-registry>/mongo:latest")
                .asCompatibleSubstituteFor("mongo");
        MongoDBContainer mongoDBContainer = new MongoDBContainer(dockerImage)
                .withImagePullPolicy(PullPolicy.defaultPolicy())
                .withExposedPorts(27019);
        mongoDBContainer.start();
```

Not alot, but that's because I can't progress any further. Any time I attempt to run this code, it gets as far as .start() before throwing the following error

```
com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.InternalServerErrorException: Status 500: {"message":"Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 192.168.65.1:53: no such host"}
```

The issue is obviously that our proxy is blocking the default registry. I could probably fiddle with proxy settings on my machine so the registry can be resolved, but that is not a company wide solution. This app will be developed and run on many different machines and environments, and reconfiguring all of them would be more effort than it's worth. Furthermore, *it shouldn't be communicating with the default registry at all.* We have our own registry for a reason. The only real solution I see here is to remove this call entirely but so far, the documentation for both [DockerImageName](https://javadoc.io/static/org.testcontainers/testcontainers/1.15.2/org/testcontainers/utility/DockerImageName.html) and the [containers](https://javadoc.io/static/org.testcontainers/testcontainers/1.15.2/org/testcontainers/containers/Container.html) have been of no help.

If anyone has attempted this, or has another solution, it would be very helpful.

Comment: You should try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65563669/9354495

Answer (score 0):

I have since realised my mistake. [This page](https://www.testcontainers.org/features/configuration) in the documentation reveals the problem. When running, the TestContainers library creates additional containers mainly for management of said containers. Unless a location is specified, it will attempt to pull these from the default registry. The preferred registry can be specified using the instructions in the link above.

As yuppie-flu also mentioned in their comment, [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65510651/how-to-configure-docker-docker-compose-to-use-nexus-by-default-instead-of-docker/65563669#65563669) may provide a nice, global way to set registries.